# Count the number of user sessions, defined as intervals

Tags: python, pandas, intervals

I have a dataset of user sessions, loaded into a Pandas DataFrame:

```
SessionID, UserID, Logon_time, Logoff_time
Adx1YiRyvOFApQiniyPWYPo,AbO6vW58ta1Bgrqs.RA0uHg,2016-01-05 07:46:56.180,2016-01-05 08:04:36.057
AfjMzw8In8RDqK6jIfItZPs,Ae8qOxLzozJHrC2pr2dOw88,2016-01-04 14:48:47.183,2016-01-04 14:53:30.210
AYIdSJYsRw5PptkFfEOXPa0,AX3Xy8dRDBRAlhyy3YaWw6U,2016-01-04 11:06:37.040,2016-01-04 16:34:38.770
Ac.WXBBSl75KqEuBmNljYPE,Ae8qOxLzozJHrC2pr2dOw88,2016-01-04 10:58:04.227,2016-01-04 11:21:10.520
AekXRDR3mBBDh49IIN2HdU8,Ae8qOxLzozJHrC2pr2dOw88,2016-01-04 10:16:08.040,2016-01-04 10:34:20.523
AVvL3VSWSq5Fr.f4733X.T4,AX3Xy8dRDBRAlhyy3YaWw6U,2016-01-04 09:19:29.773,2016-01-04 09:40:25.157
```

What I would like to do is to transform this data into a DataFrame with two columns:

- A timestamp / period (with e.g. a resolution of minute)
- The number of sessions that existed at that time

I can do this for a single timestamp, by turning the datetime ranges into an `Interval`, then checking how many rows there are where the given timestamp falls into the interval.

However, if I want to do this for one or two years, with a resolution of minute or hour, I'll end up with 8760 loops (in the case of hours) for a single year… This might not be a dealbreaker, but I was wondering if anyone had any other (possibly more elegant) suggestions or ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, we can do it this way:

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([1] * len(pd.date_range(x.Logon_time, x.Logoff_time, freq='T')), 
         index=pd.date_range(x.Logon_time, x.Logoff_time, freq='T')), axis=1)\
  .stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True).resample('T').count()
```

Output(head):

```
2016-01-04 09:19:00    1
2016-01-04 09:20:00    1
2016-01-04 09:21:00    1
2016-01-04 09:22:00    1
2016-01-04 09:23:00    1
Freq: T, dtype: int64
```

Use Pandas visualization to examine all the data:

```
df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series([1] * len(pd.date_range(x.Logon_time, x.Logoff_time, freq='T')),
                             index=pd.date_range(x.Logon_time, x.Logoff_time, freq='T')), axis=1)\
  .stack().reset_index(level=0, drop=True).resample('T').count().plot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a slightly different solution than Scott's answer, but his approach was key, as the number of observations (records) was relatively low, while on the other hand, the number of time elements (e.g. seconds, depending on the required resolution) was far greater given the elapsed time between the first and the last observation.

However, I first collected all generated date ranges (Series) into a list, and concatenated all of them in a second, separate step, which was faster than continuously modifying the original Dataframe using `apply()`.

```
# Expand the datetime range, creating records according to the given resolution (e.g. minutes).
# This creates a Series object for each session. All of those Series objects are then added to a list
# in order to concatenate them in 1 go, which is more efficient.
sessions=[]

for key, cols in df_sessions.iterrows():
    sess = pd.Series(data=pd.date_range(start=cols['logon'].floor('T'),
                                        end=cols['logoff'].ceil('T'),
                                        freq='T'),
                     name='sess_dt')
    sessions.append(sess)

# Concatenate all Series objects and convert to a DataFrame
df_sessions_2 = pd.DataFrame(pd.Series().append(sessions, ignore_index=True), columns=['ref_dt'])

# Add a counter which we can use to aggregate
df_sessions_2['sess_cnt'] = 1

# Aggregate according to the datetime
df_sessions_2 = df_sessions_2.groupby('ref_dt').sum()
```

Plotting then only requires one extra statement:

```
df_sessions_2.plot()
```

[image: Visualisation]